# injectivity radius of hyperbolic manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry

It is known that one can construct hyperbolic surfaces that have arbitrarily large injectivity radii. Is this true for higher dimensional hyperbolic manifolds? In particular I'm interested in the case of compact hyperbolic manifolds of dimension $n>4$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it just by rescaling. Let $(M,g)$ be a compact  hyperbolic manifold of dimension $n$. By compactness, it has a positive injectivity radius $r>0$. Given $R>0$, consider the manifold $(M,(R/r)g)$. Its injectivity radius is $R$.